# VBA Create New Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I recorded a macro to create a pivot table based on data in the sheet "Data." The problem is I'm not sure how to create a new sheet for the pivot table (Sheets.Add) and then immediately give it a name, since if I run this over and over I have to keep changing "SheetX" to "SheetX+1" and so on.

```
Sheets("Data").Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Feb Data!R1C1:R3000C150", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Sheet9!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Sheet9").Select
```

Comment: to change a sheet name you can use `Sheets("The name of the shee").Name = "The name you want"`

Comment: Hi Damian, that doesn't work... We've just created a new sheet with Sheets.Add, let's call it Sheet15. The code will have to be Sheets("Sheet15").Name = "Pivot" but I don't want to keep opening up the macro and editing "Sheet15," if you follow...

Comment: So you will run this macro only once everytime you need it. And you need to store the previous outputs?

Comment: Why not set `ws = application.thisworkbook.sheets.add` and then ws will be dynamic and `ws.name` will work like damian suggested. You can then just have an integer counter if you need the name to be unique and you intend to store all previous outputs.

Comment: Mostly because I wasn't aware that was a solution (not even 'decent' at VBA...still learning). Trying to use ws = application.thisworkboox.sheets.add and I'm getting Runt-ime error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Try `worksheets.add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum it up:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "PivotSheet"
End Sub
```